# Authorization header is not encrypted over HTTPS

Tags: angular, rest, http, https, basic-authentication

I am currently consuming a REST API which uses HTTP Basic Authentication.

Based on the below picture, isn't the `Authorization` header supposed to be encrypted once I am using an Angular app over an HTTPS connection?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With HTTPS, the HTTP requests/responses are sent over an SSL/TLS connection. It ensures that the entire message (including the headers) is *encrypted when it is sent over the wire*. If anyone intercepts the message, they won't be able to read the actual content.

However, the headers are still visible to both client and server. That's why Chrome DevTools and other debugging tools will show the values as plain text.

Comment: It'd be funny if all content would be encrypted at the root and it would stay that way. "I want to do basic auth!" -> the server responds: "Sorry? You want to do sddada2323headsads343? I don't understand that, let me generate a 400 response." -> The client: "Sorry? You say desadijedksadn34njsndjn34? What?"

Comment: Oh. now that makes absolute sense!!!  Thanks for the explanation Cassio.